# Regex - Don't allow only space or special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, expression

please help! I've been at this for hours.

I need a first name regex that accepts letters and the following special characters.

`-`, `'`, `.` and whitespace

However, it must NOT let the name be made up of only special characters or whitespace.

So, in essence it needs to have at least 1 letter, or start with a letter.

What I've got is this;

```
/^[a-zA-Z](|\s|.|'|-]*$)/i
```

However, it's allowing any special characters. If someone could help!

Answer (score 2):

```js
/^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\s.'-]+$/i
```

`(?=.*[a-z])` Require at least a ASCII letter. (positive lookahead)

You can either use `+` (match 1 or more) or `*` (match 0 or more).

Note: Because of the flag `i` you don't need `A-Za-z`. It's case insensitive. So only one of them is necessary. Using both with i-flag is redundant.

Trivia: Escaping `.` in character set `[...]` is not required but optional possible (`\.`).

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\s.'-]+$/i;

console.log(regex.test('Hello World'), 'should be true');
console.log(regex.test('Hello.World'), 'should be true');
console.log(regex.test('Hello-World'), 'should be true');
console.log(regex.test(`'Hello- World.'`), 'should be true');
console.log(regex.test('Hello $ World'), 'should be false');
console.log(regex.test('Hello@World'), 'should be false');
// Min. one A-Z char required. 
console.log(regex.test(`'.- `), 'should be false');
```

You can also test your regex online on e.g. [regexr](https://regexr.com/) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: This does not reject a string made up of only special characters.

Comment: console.log(regex.test("-'."), 'should be false');

Answer (score 1):

A string made up of all `-`, `'`, `.`, whitespace and letters is

```
^[-'.\sa-zA-Z]+$
```

A string that has at least one letter in it has an unlimited number of the above sandwiching a single letter:

```
^[-'.\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][-'.\sa-zA-Z]*$
```

You can denote the letters however you want. `a-zA-Z` can be just a placeholder.

Comment: @3limin4t0r thanks for the catch(es). Fixed the bounds markers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a single regex, you could also opt to use multiple. In you scenario this would be 2:

1. Check if only whitelisted characters are used.
2. Check if at least one (ASCII) letter is used.

```js
function validateName(name) {
  const whitelist = /^[-'.\sa-z]*$/i;
  const letter = /[a-z]/i;
  
  return whitelist.test(name) && letter.test(name);
}

console.log("John Doe",         "//=>", validateName("John Doe"));
console.log("John F. Kennedy",  "//=>", validateName("John F. Kennedy"));
console.log("Willem-Alexander", "//=>", validateName("Willem-Alexander"));
console.log("Jeanne d'Arc",     "//=>", validateName("Jeanne d'Arc"));
console.log("-' .",             "//=>", validateName("-' ."));
```